# Changing button text using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working in this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/4821/    I want to make the button text  change on click. I have tried different things but non seem to work for me. Any help will be appreciated. below is my html code    `<div id='content'>Category Contents</div>
<input type='button' id='hideshow' value='Show Categories'>`

is there any way i can add some transitional effect to it? i.e making the content show/hide "vertically" from top-bottom & bottom-top because by default, it is moving from left-right & right to left

Comment: Any particular reason you are using jQuery 1.4.2? , that is rather old

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ysnoLLrk/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that `<input>`s have a `value`, but you're trying to use `.text()` on it. Your first step is to change that to [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/).

Next, you're using a kinda old version of jQuery, try something more recent, and instead of [`.live()`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) (which is deprecated), use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Here's a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Hatchet/vVsAn/4823/). (Note: I did change the jQuery version to 2.2.1)

Comment: @Daniel, if this or any answer has solved your question, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the checkmark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Happy Coding!

Comment: You shouldnt change the jQuery version and methods used, do advise the OP, but dont just change them (maybe a plugin they use requires it, you just broke that..). And you dont address the fact that the button says "Show Categories"

Comment: @DelightedD0D I made it clear that the jQuery version was old, and that I changed it to be consistent with what I mentioned immediately before. The fact that the button says "Show Categories" has nothing to do with the OP's problem.

Comment: is there any way i can add some transitional effect to it? i.e making the content show/hide "vertically" from top-bottom & bottom-top because by default, it is moving from left-right & right to left.

Comment: @Daniel, if you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/4822/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var count = 0;
$('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {
$('#content').toggle('show');
count++;
    if(count % 2)
    {
       $(this).attr('value', 'Show Categories');
    }
    else
    {
       $(this).attr('value', 'Hide Categories');
    }

 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues

- You are using an input which has a `value` you can get with `.val()` not a `text` property
- You are checking for "Show Answer" but your button acutally says "Show Category"
- You should use a newer version of jQuery and `.on()` instead of `.live()` if at all possible

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {
    $this=$(this);
    $('#content').toggle();
     if ($.trim($this.val()) === 'Show Answer') {
        $this.val('Hide Answer');
    } else {
        $this.val('Show Answer');        
    }
    
    return false; 
  });
});
```

```css
#content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='content'>Category Contents</div>
<input type='button' id='hideshow' value='Show Answer'>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code.

1. You should use .val() function instead of .text()
2. Your button value is *Show Categories* not *Show Answer*

   ```
   $( document ).ready( function(){
   $('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {
       $('#content').toggle('show');
       if ($.trim($(this).val()) === 'Show Categories') {
           $(this).val('Hide Answer');
       } else {
           $(this).val('Show Answer');
       }
       return false; 
   });
   ```

   });

*Note: [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)is Deprecated as of Jquery Ver. 1.7. So use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead*

Comment: @DelightedD0D: Updated my answer! Thanks !